# Office365 PowerShell issues with DateTime variables

Tags: exchange, powershell, microsoft-office-365

I have the following very simple PowerShell snippet that just won't work.

The following works

```
Get-MessageTrace -StartDate $dateStart -EndDate $dateEnd -PageSize 5000 `
    -SenderAddress system@example.com `
    | where {$_.RecipientAddress -like "*example.com*"} `
    | Select-Object SenderAddress, RecipientAddress, Subject
```

While the following does not work

```
$dateStart = "03/20/2017"
$dateEnd = "03/27/2017"

Get-MessageTrace -StartDate $dateStart -EndDate $dateEnd -PageSize 5000 `
    -SenderAddress system@example.com `
    | where {$_.RecipientAddress -like "*example.com*"} `
    | Select-Object SenderAddress, RecipientAddress, Subject
```

Even if I replace the `$dateStart` and `$dateEnd` with various formats such as `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.`

There is no error, just no results returned, however I've used `where` patterns that I know should return something. I've also ran the  above (example that doesn't work) using today's date (which is the default when `-startdate` and `-enddate` are not specified) and that also doesn't work. Even though that is what the working example is effectively using.

So I've narrowed it down to the date but I can't see the problem. If I put in a date string that is wrong that at least gives and error, otherwise nothing. Any pointers?

Comment: I took the liberty of adding more details to your title that makes it more usable for the public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, you are currently using

```
$dateStart = "03/20/2017"
$dateEnd = "03/27/2017"
```

Because in this case the values are string of characters, Windows PowerShell will automatically use the `String` data type to store the value, while [`Get-MessageTrace`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200704(v=exchg.160).aspx) `-StartDate` and `-EndDate` only take `System.DateTime` type variables.

You can set the correct type variable by using [`Get-Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date) like this:

```
$dateStart = Get-Date "03/20/2017"
$dateEnd = Get-Date "03/27/2017"
```

Alternatively, you can create new `System.DateTime` object by specifying the type of the variable first and then assign a string value to it (if it is a value that can be cast to `System.DateTime`):

```
[System.Datetime]$dateStart = "03/20/2017"
[System.Datetime]$dateEnd = "03/27/2017"
```

However, I'd prefer `Get-Date` as it makes your script more generalizable. For example you can create a script that always gives you information on last seven days:

```
$dateEnd = Get-Date
$dateStart = (($$dateEnd).AddDays(-7))

Get-MessageTrace -StartDate $dateStart -EndDate $dateEnd -PageSize 5000 `
    -SenderAddress system@example.com `
    | where {$_.RecipientAddress -like "*example.com*"} `
    | Select-Object SenderAddress, RecipientAddress, Subject
```

**Additional hint:**

You can also use `Get-Date` for figuring out the *short date format* defined in the *Regional Options*:

```
Get-Date -Format d
```

It will give you the correct *short date pattern* you need for your `EndDate` and `StartDate` parameters.

Comment: That just gives me an error `$dateStart = Get-Date "03/20/2017"
$dateEnd = Get-Date "03/27/2017"` also from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200704(v=exchg.160).aspx I should be able to use `"03/27/2017 00:00:00"` but that also does not work

Comment: I just added a hint on how you can use `Get-Date` for figuring out the correct form. How cool is that!

Comment: Sorry I was in copy and paste mode. However I've used your `[System.Datetime]$dateStart` and it works. I had to make one amendment. When using today's date I had to add the time. Otherwise it returned " 0 results